# How can I delete message when user clicks one of inline_keyboard buttons?

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot

I'd like to know if it's possible to send a message with inline_keyboard to user of Telegram Bot and delete this message after user clicks one of the buttons of keyboard.
I send messages to users via API.

Here is my call to telegram api:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot012345678:fdvnljfnvlskn345bklbv/sendMessage?chat_id=123456789&text=Hello&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"Yes","callback_data":"Yes"},{"text":"No","callback_data":"No"}]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having `chat_id` and `message_id`, you can use [deleteMessage method](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage).

A `message_id` can can be obtained from the server response to your original `sendMessage` request (because [server returns](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) a `Message` [object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message)).

Note that there are some limitations on `deleteMessage` usage:

> - A message can only be deleted if it was sent less than **48 hours ago**.
> - Bots can delete outgoing messages in private chats, groups, and supergroups.
> - Bots granted can_post_messages permissions can delete outgoing messages in channels.
> - If the bot is an administrator of a group, it can delete any message there.
> - If the bot has can_delete_messages permission in a supergroup or a channel, it can delete any message there.